# Server sends INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, but client receives OK

Tags: spring

I've got a method on the server which returns HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR  but the client application always gets OK http status.

This is servers method (It's implified):

```
@RequestMapping(value="/example", method = RequestMethod.POST)
HttpStatus createSomething(Principal principal, @RequestBody @Valid SomeObject so) {

    return HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
}
```

I'm sure that the right request is being made by cient application. Any ideas what migh cause the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It won't work like that you should either:

```
return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus. INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

or throw some custom exception with http status:

```
ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
public class InternalServerException extends RuntimeException {
    public InternalServerException (String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```